# Automating User Zip Code Entry in Python Selenium and Chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate entering a zip code on a webpage and then scraping the text of the page that is output as a result. (Using Grocery Outlet store locater as an example for privacy reasons)

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors') 
options.add_argument('--log-level=OFF')
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.groceryoutlet.com/store-locator")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/main/div/div[1]/div/div/div/form/div/div/div/div/input").send_keys("90210")

html = driver.page_source
htmltext = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml").text
cleantext = htmltext.replace('\n','').replace('\t','').replace(',','\n')
cleantext
```

This doesn't seem to actually pass through the zip code though. The text that is scraped seems like it's just scraping the URL before entering the zip code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You typed a zip code, but you certainly did not press "Enter" or click a "Submit" button.

Comment: The "send_keys()" method is supposed to function as "enter" is it not?

Comment: No, it is not.  It sends the keys you told it to send.  It does not add anything.  If you want an "enter", then you have to send it.

Comment: Oh my :') Vert silly misunderstanding on my part, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple options you can use:

1. Send Key

   `element = options.find_element_by_id("searchBoxId") element.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)`

   The problem with this is that not every text box supports the enter/return key to search. Grocery Outlet does, but I've run into several that don't.
2. Search for Button Element then Click

   `element = options.find_element_by_id("searchButtonId") element.click()`

   Personally, I find this more reliable as the search button should always exist on the page.

It's a good idea to write a function that covers both behaviors. In my scripts, I use the click option as a failover if I can't simply send the enter/return key within the search box.

Comment: Thank you! The first one works for the case I was using, I'll use the 2nd in the exception handling.